# Error Expanding Script Generated Classpath for Java in PowerShell Script

Tags: java, powershell, shellexecute

Synopsis:
I am trying to convert a shell script from UNIX to Powershell.
The script cannot "hardcode" the path, but must instead list a directory to dynamically build the path at runtime.

Also, the script must pass in 1 parameter to indicate the "type" of the run.

I am placing my "attempted" re-write of the script (after much googling/binging)

This script might be very close as the "echo" statements produced what seems to be correct.

```
$EXE_CLASS="com.sungard.sims.dacar.standalone.Dacar"
#$DACAR_TAG=%1
$JAVA_EXE="$ENV:JDK15\jre\bin\java"
#JAVA_EXE=\opt\java\bin\java

$JARS="dist\lib\Dacar-Engine.jar;dist\lib\Dacar-Common.jar;dist\lib\Dacar-Collector.jar;dist\lib\standalone-Dacar.jar;dist\lib\DACAR-CRG.jar;"
#dynamically append all .jar files from the jars directory.
ls jars\*.jar | %  { $JARS +=";jars\"+ $_.name   }

$JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xloggc:.\engine.gc.log -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:PermSize=128m -DinstName=${DACAR_TAG} -DprocType=ENGINE"

echo "exe:   -> $JAVA_EXE"
echo "opts:  -> $JAVA_OPTS"
echo "jars:  -> $JARS"
echo "class: -> $EXE_CLASS"

& $JAVA_EXE $JAVA_OPTS "-classpath .\configuration;$JARS $EXE_CLASS 1> dacar.out 2> dacar.err"
```

please note that I have commented out the use of the DACAR_TAG which would normally be passed in as %1 in batch script containing "TEST|DEV|PROD|QA|STRESS|[CLIENT SPECIFIC VALUE]"

Here is the output:

```
PS C:\dacar> .\startDacar.ps1
exe:   -> c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre\bin\java
opts:  -> -server -Xloggc:.\engine.gc.log -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxTe
nuringThreshold=8 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:PermSize=128m -DinstName=TESTING -DprocType=ENGINE
jars:  -> dist\lib\Dacar-Engine.jar;dist\lib\Dacar-Common.jar;dist\lib\Dacar-Collector.jar;dist\lib\standalone-Dacar.jar;dist\lib\DACAR-CRG.jar;;jars\activation.jar;jars
\commons-beanutils-1.6.jar;jars\commons-codec-1.3.jar;jars\commons-collections-3.2.jar;jars\commons-configuration-1.4.jar;jars\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar;jars\commons-digester
-1.6.jar;jars\commons-discovery-0.4.jar;jars\commons-id.jar;jars\commons-lang-2.2.jar;jars\commons-logging-1.0.3.jar;jars\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar;jars\concurrent.jar;jars
\graphics.jar;jars\ha-javamail-1.0-beta-1.jar;jars\hsqldb.jar;jars\ibatis-core-3.0.jar;jars\jcommon-1.0.6.jar;jars\jconn3.jar;jars\jdom.jar;jars\jetty-6.1.15.jar;jars\je
tty-util-6.1.15.jar;jars\jfreechart-1.0.3.jar;jars\jgroups-all.jar;jars\jmxri.jar;jars\jta.jar;jars\junit.jar;jars\log4j-1.2.9.jar;jars\mailapi.jar;jars\postgresql-8.0.3
09.jdbc2ee.jar;jars\postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar;jars\quartz-1.6.0.jar;jars\servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar;jars\smtp.jar;jars\svnant.jar;jars\svnClientAdapter.jar;jars\svn
javahl.jar;jars\truezip-6.jar;jars\uic-optional.jar;jars\uic.jar
class: -> com.sungard.sims.dacar.standalone.Dacar
Unrecognized option: -server -Xloggc:.\engine.gc.log -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepG
 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:PermSize=128m -DinstName=TESTING -DprocType=ENGINE
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Adding the tag will be my next question if I can't figure this out.

JUST AS AN FYI, from with in a ps1 script I can start it the program with the following command successfully:

```
& "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin\java" -server -Xloggc:.\engine.gc.log -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:PermSize=128m -DinstName=TESTING -DprocType=ENGINE -classpath ".\configuration;dist\lib\Dacar-Engine.jar;dist\lib\Dacar-Common.jar;dist\lib\Dacar-Collector.jar;dist\lib\standalone-Dacar.jar;dist\lib\DACAR-CRG.jar;;jars\activation.jar;jars\commons-beanutils-1.6.jar;jars\commons-codec-1.3.jar;jars\commons-collections-3.2.jar;jars\commons-configuration-1.4.jar;jars\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar;jars\commons-digester-1.6.jar;jars\commons-discovery-0.4.jar;jars\commons-id.jar;jars\commons-lang-2.2.jar;jars\commons-logging-1.0.3.jar;jars\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar;jars\concurrent.jar;jars\graphics.jar;jars\ha-javamail-1.0-beta-1.jar;jars\hsqldb.jar;jars\ibatis-core-3.0.jar;jars\jcommon-1.0.6.jar;jars\jconn3.jar;jars\jdom.jar;jars\jetty-6.1.15.jar;jars\jetty-util-6.1.15.jar;jars\jfreechart-1.0.3.jar;jars\jgroups-all.jar;jars\jmxri.jar;jars\jta.jar;jars\junit.jar;jars\log4j-1.2.9.jar;jars\mailapi.jar;jars\postgresql-8.0.309.jdbc2ee.jar;jars\postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar;jars\quartz-1.6.0.jar;jars\servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar;jars\smtp.jar;jars\svnant.jar;jars\svnClientAdapter.jar;jars\svnjavahl.jar;jars\truezip-6.jar;jars\uic-optional.jar;jars\uic.jar" com.sungard.sims.dacar.standalone.Dacar
```

But that is not really an option, as That is just invoking the thing in a hard coded fashion.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note about PowerShell variable expansion is that if it's anything more than a simple $VARIABLE expression you typically need to escape it using curly braces or a sub-expression.

So this line:

```
$JAVA_EXE="$ENV:JDK15\jre\bin\java"
```

Could be represented as either:

```
$JAVA_EXE="${ENV:JDK15}\jre\bin\java"
```

or...

```
$JAVA_EXE="$($ENV:JDK15)\jre\bin\java"
```

> EDIT: Apparently PowerShell does
>   correctly evaluate all 3 examples. I
>   seem to recall the first syntax not
>   working but perhaps that was in
>   PowerShell 1.0 or a CTP...

Another useful tip that I often suggest people do when working with external .exe commands is to map it to an alias using the Set-Alias command. This way it makes working with the command a lot more natural as you don't have to use the &"string" syntax.

```
Set-Alias java "$($ENV:JDK15)\jre\bin\java.exe"
java blah1 blah2 etc
```

Comment: made the changes suggested, and while it might add to the readability of the script, it give generally the same error:
java.exe : Unrecognized option: -server -Xloggc:.\engine.gc.log -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseCon
cMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:PermSize=128m -DinstName= -DprocType=ENGINE
At C:\dacar\startDacar.ps1:16 char:5
+ java <<<<  $JAVA_OPTS "-classpath .\configuration;$JARS" $EXE_CLASS 1> dacar.out 2> dacar [truncated]

Comment: Josh: Within strings a colon is still considered part of the variable name, so `$Env:Foo` *does* work as expected within a double-quoted string. You don't need to use `$()` or `${}` there.

Comment: Any Idea why I can't get this simple test to work?  Should I make a simple downloaded example?  or is there enough detail from above to see a potential issue?

Comment: @Johannes, yes I edited my answer shortly after posting once I realized the mistake. Do you happen to know if 1.0 treated that differently? I consider myself a pretty advanced PowerShell user and somehow all this time I thought the colon "terminated" the variable expression.

Comment: @Q Boiler, I think the issue is that you are packing multiple options into a single string variable which is then being passed to the external command line parser as a single parameter. In other words, consider this: $f = "C:\Path with space\blah.txt"; SomeCommand $f; When PowerShell calls SomeCommand it will pass $f with quotes around it so it's treated like a single parameter. Can you break up your $java_opts variable into a combination of static text and multiple variables? Finally, the redirection args at the end won't be interpreted the way you think. Move them out of the string literal.

Comment: Josh: PowerShell v1 was the same in that regard; just tried it. It can make things a little awkward sometimes when you want to print a colon directly after a variable expansion, where you then have to escape the colon (or wrap the variable expansion; but escaping the colon is shorter). In fact, if you don't consider the special syntax to access items in PSDrives (which `$Env:Foo` is, essentially), then it's probably perfectly natural to assume that a colon isn't part of a variable name – most languages aren't that forgiving about naming ;-)